# Scrapy and multiple items.py files?

Tags: scrapy

My items.py file is getting pretty huge and it's difficult to see which function belongs to which items.

Is it possible to have multiple of these files so I can spread my code?

Comment: Do you have a huge amount of `scrapy.Field()` or huge amount of process functions for each field?

Comment: I have multiple classes, each with 5-10 `scrapy.Field()`s